# Maximum and Minimum Probability

Tags: probability

> Let A be an event with a probability of 50% and B be an event with a probability 30%.  What is the maximum and minimum of $P(A∩B)$?

My first problem with this question is how can a probability have a min and max?  I don't understand how that can be a thing since that should be a set number.  The way I would solve this I'm assuming is $P(A∩B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$ and we would plug in $.5+.3-((.5+.3)-(.5)(.3))=.5+.3-.65=.15.$  So how would I find the max and min probability from here?

Comment: Whoa., hold up... I see somewhere that you multiplied $0.5$ and $0.3$.  Why?  You aren't told that $A$ and $B$ are independent.  You may never multiply two probabilities together of two different events and expect the result to have any meaning unless you happen to know ahead of time that $A$ and $B$ are independent.  It looks like you might have known this in the back of your mind too and tried using inclusion exclusion to replace $Pr(A\cap B)$ with the other terms, but then used inclusion exclusion to find $Pr(A\cup B)$ in that expansion and ignored it at that point.

Comment: To understand what the problem is asking, suppose that the event $A$ is fixed but the event $B$ is not.  The question then asks, given that we can choose the event $B$ however we like, how large can we make $P(A\cap B)$?  How small can we make it?

Comment: The maximum is when $A$ and $B$ overlap as much as possible, which happens when $A$ or $B$ happens to be a subset of the other.  The minimum is when $A$ and $B$ overlap as little as possible, which for these numbers occurs when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: I was confused because if they were not independent then .5+.3-(.5+.3)=0 and that would be incorrect, correct?

Comment: When you replaced $P(A\cup B)$ by $.5+.3-(.5)(.3)$... that was you using inclusion-exclusion again, the $(.5)(.3)$ having been what *should* have been $P(A\cap B)$ which is not able to be calculated from the given information but could have been calculated in the case that $A$ and $B$ were independent.  All that we can get from inclusion-exclusion here is a way to bound the probability from below.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1
\end{align*}
Since $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\geq 0$, it results that
$$\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq \max\{\textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1,0\}.$$

On the other hand, $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Thus $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\leq \textbf{P}(A)$ and $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\leq \textbf{P}(B)$, therefore
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\leq \min\{\textbf{P}(A),\textbf{P}(B)\}
\end{align*}
As a consequence of both results, we obtain the desired bounds:
\begin{align*}
\max\{\textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1,0\} \leq \textbf{P}(A\cap B)\leq \min\{\textbf{P}(A),\textbf{P}(B)\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand everything till the last part.  The max you say is .5+.3-1,0 which says {-.2,0} and the min is {.5,.3} I don't understand how that shows us the max and min?

Comment: @user710744 The last part says that $\min\{\mathsf P(A),\mathsf P(B)\}$ is the *maximum* value that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ could plausibly have. $~$ (Don't confuse this maximum with the $\max$ function.) $~$ Likewise it says that $\max\{\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-1,0\}$, that is $0$, is the *minimum* value that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ might plausibly have. $~$ These are the bounds on the realistic values of the probability for the intersection. $$0.0\leqslant \mathsf P(A\cap B)\leqslant 0.3$$

Comment: You are tasked to find the minimum and maximum value of the interval on which $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ may exist and beyond which it cannot possibly be found.